# Print left-aligned formatted float with suffix text

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to easily format and **left-align** a quantity that is a compound of **float plus string** (in my case the string is a unit of measure), using the standard format_spec syntax.

Using underscores to represent *consumed space*:

```
>>> print '{:<20.2f} {:s}'.format(1.0, 'kg/hr')
1.00_________________kg/hr
```

But what I really want is a convenient way of producing this:

```
1.00_kg/hr________________
```

Furthermore, I would like the total width to be the `width` component of the format_spec, in this case 20 (but I want a general solution). In my incorrect example above, the final width of the result is actually 26, because 20 was reserved entirely for the float.

I have already searched Google and SO and have not found anything.  My fallback is to write a hacky format_spec parser to filter out the float formatting parts, apply that to make the float become a string and then reconstruct a new format_spec that I apply to the concatenation of the two. I am overriding `__format__()` in a class, so I receive the format_spec when `'{:<20.2f}'.format(my_obj)` is called (`my_obj` internally contains the unit of measure, which must be shown when `__repr__()` is called).  Proposed pseudocode:

```
def __format__(self, format_spec):

    float_spec = extract_float_part(format_spec)
    # Using the example above, float_spec becomes '.2f'

    float_str = string.format(float_value, float_spec)
    # Using example, float_str becomes '1.00'

    new_format_spec = make_new_format_spec(format_spec)
    # Using example, new_format_spec should become '<20s'

    output = string.format(' '.join([float_str, unit_str]), new_format_spec)
```

I really don't want to write (nor have to maintain) `extract_float_part()` and `make_new_format_spec()`.  It will be easy to do for a subset of cases (e.g. detect for, and split at the period, etc.) but I am worried that there will be lots of corner cases and I'll have to add a lot of boilerplate to handle them. In general, the format_spec could be whatever is allowed in the standard format function, and any standard errors that are triggered should propagate and be reported correctly for the float part.

Is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding you, but is this what you want?

```
>>> print '{:.2f} {:<20}'.format(1.0, 'kg/hr')
1.00_kg/hr_______________
```

Comment: I should have used your example in my post!  It still presents problems though, because how do I deal with `'{:<20.2f}'.format(my_obj)`? In other words, the user of my class is going to pass a single field width in.  So I think I would still have to parse and extract the given field width in the user-provided format spec, and then do the math to calculate the sizes for each of the float and units parts?

Comment: Also, the alignment issues remain, because the user could specify either `<` or `>`, so I would have to check for and extract that too...maybe I will end up having to do some parsing of the format_spec anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem (in the comment above, to pass a single field) you may try:

```
d = {'value':1.0, 'unit':'kg/hr'}
print '{value:.2f} {unit:<20}'.format(**d)
```

where `d` may be a dictionary member of your class.

Also, I would just filter the value to accept only floats.